# Where does Ethereum Dapps go in known design paterns

Tags: solidity, contract-development, design-patterns

I am doing a Dapp for a school project and I am supposed to choose a design pattern to work with.

I want to know the possibilities for design patterns concerning the ethereum dapps, or if they have some special design pattern of their own.